# What is a good syntax highlighter?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm looking for a good syntax highlighter for my site that uses PHP & MySQL and Jquery. A syntax highlighter that does not let the code overlap but allows the user to scroll like here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Wouldn't the "overlap" issue be fixed by setting the CSS `overflow: auto;` on the div containing the formatted source code?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely all PHP source code highlighters based on Geshi library http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

You can make code blocks "not let the code overlap but allows the user to scroll" by adding CSS `overflow : auto;`

Also good way is to use JavaScript based code highlighters that highlight code on client side http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ or http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

Answer (score 1):

The scrolling is just a CSS property of whatever the code is in - something like...

```
max-height: 600px;
overflow: auto;
```

(The `overflow` attribute tells the browser to use scrollbars, the `max-height` tells it at what point the vertical scrollbar should kick in.)

As for hilighting, take a look at [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: I'm being nitpicky.  I know this.  Don't take it personally.  overflow:auto tell the container to use scrollbars IF it needs them  to fit the content.  If the content fits, no scrollbars are displayed.

Comment: @Surreal, yes. I never actually stated that it *always* uses them. :)

Comment: Sorry, should have left that alone.  Your answer was good without my picking.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Highligter has brushes for php, sql, js and etc.
[how-to for blog](http://inetstd.blogspot.com/2011/06/syntaxhighligter-3-fix-scroll-height-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a client side solution try :
[alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)

or

http://codemirror.net/

Both of them have support for sql, javascript and php

As for the overlap, you can add a div parent and play with the css to custom the behavior

Answer (score 0):

Please check **Prettify GC Syntax Highlighter**. But as described in [Here](http://www.technologyspirit.com/prettify-gc-syntax-highlighter-one-of-the-stable-syntax-highlighter-plugin/), you may need to do little modifications to the CSS file of the plugin.